# undefined local variable or method `student_courses' for #<Class:0x000055ee7729d680> after creating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i created a model called `Student Courses` and then i migrate the database,the page was working well before doing that and i was trying to create a has_many model for my databasei created a model called `StudentCourses` and then i migrated the database, before thoing that the page were working

i used Scaffold to create Student with name, last name and email, the same for courses but courses only have a name for it

Student:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :student_courses
    has_many :courses, through: student_courses
end
```

Course:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :student_courses
    has_many :students, through: student_courses
end
```

this is my StudentCourse model:

```
class StudentCourse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end
```

the problem must be in my Student controller?

Comment: Shows the errors from your server console... It looks like you're trying to call `student_courses` on a class and not an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The association is configured using a symbol

```
has_many :courses, through: :student_courses
```

note the ":" before "student_courses"

Comment: THANKS you so much <3, thats resolve all the problem and now i can create data in the console